# In SharePoint How to create a form that changes based on a drop down selection

Tags: forms, sharepoint, office365

I need to create a dynamic form/workflow in SharePoint. What I am trying to do is create a form that has a drop-down selector with 2 options **Projects** and **Proposals**. Depending on which of those two the submitter chooses the form will change which fields are displayed in the form below them.

The goal is the have the form populate 1 list and just populate different fields depending on the form type chosen.

Is this easily doable?

Our SharePoint environment is being provided by Microsoft's Office365 solution.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try Content Types ? You'll not get drop-down (however I've seen drop-down for document libraries with content types), but you can achieve your target: when creating new item you can select which type of item to create (Project or Proposal) and when you'll get fields according to that content type. All data will be stored in the same table.